# How to port an android 11 kernel to android 12

Tags: android, linux-kernel, kernel, android-source

I want to port a custom kernel which works on android 11 to android 12.

https://github.com/morogoku/MoRoKernel-S7
This is the kernel i want to port
I need some help regarding how to start or what to do.

https://github.com/8890q/android_kernel_samsung_universal8890
This is the android 12 kernel

The Android 11 kernel does boot on android 12 but some features like bluetooth doesnt work so i figured there shouldnt be much to change.

I want to make it work on android 12

Comment: Why do you need a forward port? I.o.w. what's wrong with the newer kernel from AOSP12?

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the best solution to your problem but I would go about it this way, but backporting stuff seems the way to go, since IMHO I don't think there is a direct solution.

1. See the changes in kernel/common from AOSP for Android 12 and try to port the patches required. But since your kernel is 3.18, I am not sure it can directly go for A12/A13, backporting things are a huge effort.
2. You should take a look at the kernel changes what communities like LineageOS or Paranoid Android do to support older devices with 3.18.x kernel to run on Android 12 and higher.
3. Take reference from similar devices from #2 for all subsystems and drivers required.
4. For vendor specific modules like bluetooth support, try to see if you have any support from #3. In many cases it might be as easy as applying certain commits or it might be as difficult as getting a full port done.